# Как избежать блокировки телеграм при регистрации через telethon?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Предвидя комментарии о спаме, небольшая предыстория. Пишу сервис для колл-центра, все общение сотрудников происходит через веб морду (общение логируется), оператор не начинает разговор первым, то есть отвечает на присланные ему сообщения (это ограничено бизнес логикой приложения). Подозрительной активности нет, сообщения отправляются клиентам через очередь celery с delay в секунду. Спам/вступление в чужие группы/парсинг сообщений не настраивал, то есть активность приложения - минимальна.

После регистрации происходит перманентный бан, собственно вопрос - из-за чего? Правила сервиса, вроде как, не нарушаются, пробовал менять апи ключ, прокси сервер (т.к. в России телеграм заблокирован приходится использовать его), смс номера (пробовал как с купленными симкартами, так и с базой номеров), также играл с задержкой в секундах на разных этапах регистрации. При этом бан происходит на этапе создания 1 юзера (частота создания на продакшене также будет минимальна т.к. кол-во операторов около 10 и сам факт обновления номера явление редкое, только в случае расширения персонала)

Пример кода (это простой пример, написанный на коленке, в самом проекте логики чуть больше, но даже на приведенном ниже примере я получаю бан)

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync
from tg_person.person import tg_config
import time
import socks

from tg_person.sms import PhoneService

client = TelegramClient(
    f'sessions/TestUserNms',
    **tg_config,
    proxy=(socks.SOCKS5, '166.62.80.198', 18726)
)

activation = PhoneService.get_tg_phone()

client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(
        activation.phone_number)

code = input('Enter code: ')

time.sleep(20)
client.sign_up(code, 'SomeUserNameField')
client.disconnect()
```

P.s. возможно, нарушены какие-либо правила сервиса, если да, хотелось бы получить на них ссылку и прочитать (т.к. задача только в планах, возможно стоит сменить брокер сообщений на что-нибудь аналогичное, типа вайбера/ватсапа)
Прокси сервер заместо указанного использую свой, поднятый через dante (банометр молчит, запросов с него минимум, только для тестов)

Comment: Я что-то так и не понял, зачем эта регистрация вообще нужна? По идее всё общение можно организовать через одного-единственного телеграм-бота

Comment: @Артур тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой. Только у меня именно парсинг и мой новый аккаунт банили сразу. Во первых, вам нужен номер телефона, у которого есть большая активность, подписки на группы и т.д. Новые аккаунты не подходят, их банят сразу. Срок, который нужно чтобы новый аккаунт превратился в норм, не определен

Comment: И это не проблема библиотеки, это проблема телеграмма

Comment: @andreymal через бота не позволяет тз реализовать. Нужно именно пользовательские аккаунты. Не вдаваясь в подробности это связано с с политикой компании, проверками, а также делегированием задач.

Comment: @danilshik то что это проблема телеграма я прочитал в исшью, одного не могу понять, теже самые номера зарегистрированные в оф приложениях (и даже в форках) работают. Как же регистрируют люди в таких приложениях? Как получить активность до регистрации), мне почему-то кажется что тут не все так просто.

Comment: А у вас на физические симки бан идет чтоль?

Comment: @danilshik и физически, и через виртуальные номера. На виртуальные собственно перешел из-за того что физические закончились, тобиш для дебага.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync
```

Использовать

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
```